# GUI applications installed with homebrew cannot be launched using Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight, homebrew

I have installed cocoa versions of both Emacs and MacVim using homebrew. After the installation, the actual applications are installed in `/usr/local/opt/emacs/Emacs.app` and `/usr/local/opt/macvim/MacVim.app`

They are then symlinked to `/Applications`

They now appear in my Applications folder, but if I want to start them using Spotlight, they do not turn up in the search results when I start typing (like other applications do)

Is there anything I can do to remedy this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many workarounds for this,

- you can copy Emacs and MacVim direclty to your `/Applications` folder : `cp -r /usr/local/opt/emacs/Emacs.app /Applications/` and `cp -r /usr/local/opt/macvim/MacVim.app /Applications/`.
- You can run `sudo chflags nohidden /usr`, /usr folder is flagged as hidden but not /opt, this command will unhide /usr so that Spotlight could index it (Spotlight doesn't index hidden directories).
- You can also make a shell script and [appify](http://git.abackstrom.com/appify.git) it

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  open /usr/local/opt/emacs/Emacs.app
  ```
- There is also an option in homebrew , I've not tested it personnaly, that fixes this issue : `brew linkapps --system`, you can remove --system if you want brew to link your.app to `~/Applications` instead of `/Applications`

Comment: I have tried `brew linkapps`. It creates a symlink in `/Applications/` to the right thing, but Spotlight still doesn't find it. However, if I “Make Alias” in Finder and put that in `/Applications/`, it does find it. (Note: I'm trying with `IDLE 3.app`, not Emacs or MacVim.)